# SharePoint page layout scale different

Tags: css, sharepoint, layout

I have recently deployed a solution from Development into Staging but the scale of pages on Staging are noticably different to how they were rendered in Dev.  It's the same on pages with the default master page like settings.aspx pages [image] see how the grey ribbon doesn't quite line up when they are put side by side.

The s4-workspace div has a style element attribute applied to it on the default pages, but when using the custom master these don't exist.  Also changing the attribute values to be the same on the two sites in the browser dev tools doesn't make any difference to the display.[image]

The corev15.css of the two servers are not quite the same which is interesting, but the differences are so small and definately aren't causing the issue.

Comment: Just noticed, this is a firefox only issue.  Renders the same size in both IE and interestingly Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This phenomenon disappeared without a fix.

It was suggested to me yesterday by a colleague that it might have been a zoom setting in IE.  I've just set one browser to 105% and another next to it at 100% and it was an idential the originally identified size differential.

Looks like it was an accidental Ctrl+Mouse_Wheel_Scroll.